# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view' in Seaborn , Scatterplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am getting a bizarre exception in Seaborn.

For a reproducible example:

```
toy_data.to_json()
'{"X":{"0":0.12765045,"1":0.0244816152,"2":0.1263715245,"3":0.0246376768,"4":0.1108581319,"5":0.1406719382,"6":0.1358105564,"7":0.1245863432,"8":0.1175445352,"9":0.1188479018,"10":0.1113148159,"11":0.117455495,"12":0.110555662,"13":0.1328567106,"14":0.103064284,"15":0.1119474442,"16":0.119390455,"17":0.1246727756,"18":0.1117827155,"19":0.1169972547},"Y":{"0":0.1241083714,"1":0.1394242378,"2":0.1225010796,"3":0.0077080173,"4":0.1198371354,"5":0.0029026989,"6":0.1259473297,"7":0.0,"8":0.0,"9":0.1214620231,"10":0.1204110739,"11":0.0,"12":0.1194570059,"13":0.0014971676,"14":0.1184584731,"15":0.1212061305,"16":0.1221438778,"17":0.0,"18":0.1209991075,"19":0.0},"Label":{"0":"17","1":"3","2":"17","3":"0","4":"14","5":"21","6":"16","7":"23","8":"20","9":"15","10":"14","11":"20","12":"14","13":"22","14":"13","15":"14","16":"15","17":"23","18":"14","19":"20"},"Probability":{"0":1.0,"1":1.0,"2":1.0,"3":1.0,"4":1.0,"5":1.0,"6":1.0,"7":1.0,"8":1.0,"9":1.0,"10":1.0,"11":1.0,"12":1.0,"13":1.0,"14":1.0,"15":1.0,"16":1.0,"17":1.0,"18":0.9101796407,"19":1.0}}'

toy_data.head()
       X           Y    Label   Probability
0   0.127650    0.124108    17  1.0
1   0.024482    0.139424    3   1.0
2   0.126372    0.122501    17  1.0
3   0.024638    0.007708    0   1.0
4   0.110858    0.119837    14  1.0

sns.scatterplot(x = toy_data.X, y = toy_data.Y, hue = toy_data.Label.values, alpha = 0.5)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'
```

Similar exception with this syntax:

```
sns.scatterplot(x = 'X', y = 'Y', data = toy_data, hue = 'Label', alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1515

Comment: You should change your `'Label'` column to numbers. That'll probably do it. Unless they truly are categorical.

Answer (score 20):

This is a peculiar issue with seaborn where the **color `palette` needs to equal the number of labels**

```py
sns.scatterplot(x = toy_data.X, y = toy_data.Y, hue = toy_data.Label, alpha = 0.5,
                palette=sns.color_palette("Set1", toy_data.Label.nunique()) )
```

If not, seaborn will apply numerical functions to map the number of `hue` categories to the default `palette` of **four** colours. This is why you get an error when the values are a **string**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO, because it does not force the hue to be numeric (think truly categorical data such as zip codes).  And just in case it's not clear enough: all we need to do is add the palette argument with custom number of colors.

Answer (score 5):

As presented, your column Label is an object. It need to be a number (int or float).

```
toy_data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 20 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
X              20 non-null float64
Y              20 non-null float64
Label          20 non-null object
Probability    20 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 800.0+ bytes
```

Do this:

```
toy_data.loc[:,'Label'] = toy_data.Label.astype(np.float)
```

to change it to float.

Then your command:

```
sns.scatterplot(x = toy_data.X, y = toy_data.Y, hue = toy_data.label.values, alpha = 0.5)
```

should work.

[image]

I am using this command to generate the data frame

```
dict = {"X":{"0":0.12765045,"1":0.0244816152,"2":0.1263715245,"3":0.0246376768,"4":0.1108581319,"5":0.1406719382,"6":0.1358105564,"7":0.1245863432,"8":0.1175445352,"9":0.1188479018,"10":0.1113148159,"11":0.117455495,"12":0.110555662,"13":0.1328567106,"14":0.103064284,"15":0.1119474442,"16":0.119390455,"17":0.1246727756,"18":0.1117827155,"19":0.1169972547},"Y":{"0":0.1241083714,"1":0.1394242378,"2":0.1225010796,"3":0.0077080173,"4":0.1198371354,"5":0.0029026989,"6":0.1259473297,"7":0.0,"8":0.0,"9":0.1214620231,"10":0.1204110739,"11":0.0,"12":0.1194570059,"13":0.0014971676,"14":0.1184584731,"15":0.1212061305,"16":0.1221438778,"17":0.0,"18":0.1209991075,"19":0.0},"Label":{"0":"17","1":"3","2":"17","3":"0","4":"14","5":"21","6":"16","7":"23","8":"20","9":"15","10":"14","11":"20","12":"14","13":"22","14":"13","15":"14","16":"15","17":"23","18":"14","19":"20"},"Probability":{"0":1.0,"1":1.0,"2":1.0,"3":1.0,"4":1.0,"5":1.0,"6":1.0,"7":1.0,"8":1.0,"9":1.0,"10":1.0,"11":1.0,"12":1.0,"13":1.0,"14":1.0,"15":1.0,"16":1.0,"17":1.0,"18":0.9101796407,"19":1.0}}
toy_data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

You will need numpy `import numpy as np` to convert the values to float

Comment: No, the hue variable can be categorical OR numeric. See documentation here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html