# seaborn hue for numbers as strings

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm new to `seaborn` and I have this dataset and want to create a graph like this, but with `seaborn`.

[image]

This is my data:

```
max_depth = [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7, 10, 10,
       10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 15, 20, 25, 2, 5, 15, 20, 25, 2, 5,
   15, 20, 25, 2, 5, 15, 20, 25, 2, 5, 15, 20, 25]
test_score = [0.85089537, 0.85089537, 0.85089537, 0.85348114, 0.85354819, 0.87357118, 0.87328475, 0.87147859, 0.87425471, 0.87402261,
       0.86355856, 0.86120602, 0.87259394, 0.87582926, 0.87943536, 0.80913078, 0.82786446, 0.86109688, 0.86773115, 0.87619951,
       0.79090683, 0.8038633 , 0.84915534, 0.86083209, 0.87192132]

results_DT = pd.DataFrame({'max_depth': max_depth, 'min_samples_split': min_samples_split, 'test_score': test_score})
```

And this is my attempt in `seaborn`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x = 'max_depth', y = 'test_score', hue = 'min_samples_split', marker = 'o', data = results_DT) # need to work out how to fix this
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.xlabel("Max depth")
plt.ylabel("Mean CV score")
```

But as you can see, the categories are incorrect:

[image]

And when I try to convert it to string, it comes up with an error.

```
#convert   
results_DT2 = results_DT
    results_DT2['min_samples_split'] = results_DT2['min_samples_split'].astype(str)

sns.lineplot(x = 'max_depth', y = 'test_score', hue = 'min_samples_split', marker = 'o', data = results_DT2) # need to work out how to fix this
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.xlabel("Max depth")
plt.ylabel("Mean CV score")
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the min_samples_split column to categorical:

```
results_DT.min_samples_split = pd.Categorical(results_DT.min_samples_split)
sns.lineplot(x = 'max_depth', y = 'test_score', hue = 'min_samples_split', marker = 'o', data = results_DT)
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks. This is a better way of converting to categorical too.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x = 'max_depth', y = 'test_score', hue = 'min_samples_split', marker = 'o', data = results_DT, palette=sns.color_palette("Set1", results_DT.min_samples_split.nunique())) # need to work out how to fix this
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.xlabel("Max depth")
plt.ylabel("Mean CV score")
```

as mentioned and explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030855/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-view-in-seaborn-scatterplot)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.